# Type issues while converting snapshot to list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a snapshot to a list. I have been given some code by people here to help with it but I am still getting an error.

This is the error:
[image]

I am not sure how to fix this error so I am asking for some help.

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                  List<Events> eventsList = [];
                  for (var snapshotEvent in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                    Events event = Events.fromJson(snapshotEvent.data());
                    eventsList.add(event);
                  }
                  return _buildTableCalendar(eventsList);
                } else {
                  return _buildTableCalendar();
                }
              }
```

Here is the code for the fromJson function:

```
factory Events.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Events(
      id: doc.id,
      eventName: data['eventName'],
      eventStartTime: (data['eventStartTime'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDuration: data['eventDuration'],
      eventDate: (data['eventDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      eventDescription: data['eventDescription'],
      userId: data['userId'],
      companyId: data['companyId'],
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your help